# Stories not rendering in 6.1.15 version of storybook

Tags: frontend, render, storybook

My main.js file:

[image: main.js]

Its not rendering stories inside Header.stories.js

[image: Header.js]

[image: Header.stories.js]

Even I have explicitly included Header.stories.js but still the same issue, it's not being rendered.
Please see if anyone could help me with this as I am really stuck on this issue.

PS: Use following repo to reproduce the issue or to see the implementation!
[click here to see the repo](https://github.com/ashna99/Storybook_demo/tree/master)

Comment: do you have a repo to try to reproduce this issue ?

Comment: @JérémieB https://github.com/ashna99/Storybook_demo/tree/master

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this error in the console :

```
WARNING in ./src/components/Header.stories.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: Storybook_demo/my_storybook/src/components/Header.stories.js: Const declarations require an initialization value (16:20)

  14 | }
  15 |
> 16 | export const Primary ()=>(<Header >'hii'</Header>);
     |                     ^
```

I can see the `=`sign in your file, I honestly don't know why it doesn't work. It's look like a bug in a babel parser ?

However, you can make it work with juste a space between `Primary` and `=`:

```js
export const Primary = ()=>(<Header >'hii'</Header>)
```

Comment: You're correct. I didn't realise the importance of warning as I couldn't figure out what was going wrong. @JérémieB Thankyou